# Как вызвать обычную функцию в callback хендлере

Tags: python, aiogram, callback

есть функция menu:

```
async def menu(message: types.Message):
    user_stat = db.get_user_stat(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer(f"<b>Ваш ID: {user_stat[0]}       Имя: {user_stat[3]}</b>", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.main_markup)
```

есть callback:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback_query(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == 'back_to_menu':
        await menu(call.message) <- Как ее правильно вызвать?
```

Выдает ошибку: IndexError: list index out of range

Как вызвать функцию menu в callback хендлере

Comment: Юзера нет в базе . проверяйте базу

Comment: есть все...............

Comment: Ошибка говорит что нет. Или неправильно вычитываете